# filter out a deeply nested object and return a new object

Tags: json, loops, object, filter, lodash

I have a 4 level nested object which looks like this

```
{
  "name": "“Mike”",
  "id": 1000,
  "img": "“#”",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "“Jack”",
      "id": 1100,
      "img": "#",
      "married": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "”Julia“",
          "id": 1110,
          "img": "#"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "”Lily“",
      "id": 1200,
      "img": "#",
      "married": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "”Coco“",
          "id": 1210,
          "img": "#",
          "married": true,
          "children": {
            "name": "”Olivia“",
            "id": 1211,
            "img": "#",
            "married": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have an array of `idToDisplay = ["1000","1100","1200","1210"]`
I want to filter out the IDs and leave out the parts which do not match `idToDisplay` so that I can get a new object looks like this

```
{
  "name": "“Mike”",
  "id": 1000,
  "img": "“#”",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "“Jack”",
      "id": 1100,
      "img": "#",
      "married": true,
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "”Lily“",
      "id": 1200,
      "img": "#",
      "married": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "”Coco“",
          "id": 1210,
          "img": "#",
          "married": true,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the best way to iterate? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to modify your data in-place you can recursively traverse it like this:

```
var data = ... your data ...
var ids = [1000, 1100]
var handleNode = function(node) {
    node.children = node.children.filter(x => ids.includes(x.id))
    node.children.forEach(handleNode)
}
if (!ids.includes(data.id)) {data = {}}
handleNode(data)
```

Afterwards your data only consists of nodes with matching IDs.